# Timeout change args without re setTimeout

Tags: node.js

```
const timer = setTimeout(({a, b}) => {
    console.log(a + b)
}, 3000, {a:1, b:2});

setTimeout(() => {
    Object.assign(timer._timerArgs,[{a:2, b:2}])
}, 1000)

// Output: 4
```

Please have a look at this. What I'm going to do is, going to change the timer args if needed before it's called.
I don't want to use **clearTimeout** and **setTimeout** again for this process.
 But not sure this is the right way. And plus how can I set the priority per each timer in case the timeout will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got `._timerArgs` from.  I've never seen that.  Without dipping into undocumented properties (that are only present in node.js), you can do it like this:

```js
const objA = {a:1, b:2};
const timer = setTimeout(({a, b}) => {
    console.log(a + b);
}, 500, objA);

objA.a = 2;
objA.b = 3;
```

This will output `5` which reflects that you changed the property values before the timer callback fired.

Since objects in Javascript are passed by pointer (not copied), you can still modify the object that `objA` points at any time before the timer fires and see the effect inside the timer callback.

---

But, then you don't even have to pass the arguments into the `setTimeout()`.  You can just reference a parent scoped variable in the callback:

```js
const objA = {a:1, b:2};
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(objA.a + objA.b);
}, 500);

objA.a = 2;
objA.b = 3;
```

This will also output `5`.

---

If you want arbitrary argument modification (not properties embedded in an object), and you want it to be only using supported, standard tools that work in all implementations of Javascript, then you can't do that with just `setTimeout()`.  You could make your own timer wrapper though:

```js
class MyTimer {
    constructor(fn, t, ...args) {
        this.args = args;
        this.fired = false;
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.fired = true;
            fn.apply(null, this.args);
        }, t);
    }
    cancel() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
    hasFired() {
        return this.fired;
    }
}

const timer = new MyTimer((...args) => {
    console.log("timer callback arguments:", args);
}, 500, "hello", "goodbye");
timer.args = ["ola", "adios", "amor", "amigo"];
```

You can then modify the array in the `.args` property at any time before the timer fires and they will be passed to the timer callback.

Comment: Ok. let's say I'm not using the const variable objA.
The timeout args will be dynamic.

Comment: @sjhumili - Well, do you realize that `_timerArgs` does not exist in some implementations of Javascript (such as Chrome)?  There is no documented way to access the callback args that were previously passed to `setTimeout()`.  So, if you want to affect them in any universal way, you have to pass an object and then modify the properties on THAT object which you will have to keep a reference to somehow.  FYI, in Chrome, `typeof timer` is a number.  It doesn't have properties like you might see in node.js.  So, `._timerArgs` is completely non-standard.

Comment: @sjhumili - So, if you're trying to make the args completely dynamic (and not embedded in an object), there's no standard way to do that.  Perhaps you could hack one specific implementation.  You can't hack Chrome's implementation at all.  I'd suggest you make your own timerWrapper function that allows arbitrary arg modification.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: @sjhumili - OK, I added an example of a wrapper class that lets you arbitrarily change timer arguments any timer before it fires.  You could even change how many arguments there were.

Comment: @sjhumili - Does my last example, do what you want?

Comment: thanks for your answer and comments. It's very helpful!